# Walking on a road in Spain

Tags: spain, walking

As a tourist, I am thinking of visiting nearby city in Pyrenees, but the only way is to take the road so I might meet a lot of cars. Is it legal to walk on a road in Spain?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is, on public roads except where indicated with a sign like this:

[image: No Pedestrians sign]

Note though there was consideration given to make walking while drunk an offence: [The Grauniad](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2015/feb/25/spain-wants-to-ban-drunk-walking-what-next-for-pedestrians).

General advice for pedestrians is available at: [Just Landed](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Spain/Articles/Travel-Leisure/Pedestrian-Road-Rules).

One one occasion I was staggering so much I risked falling over a cliff had I not aimed to follow the white line down the middle of the road. However I do NOT recommend that.

Comment: Think you should add the first two lines of those: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_of_Spain#Information_signs

Comment: I mean the first signs below the title "Information signs". It is about motorways indeed.

Comment: Note that there are derivatives of the sign (for example, those at motorway accesses: they prohibit pedestrians _and_ some vehicles). And please, walk on the left side shoulder (i.e. facing traffic).

Comment: @pnuts true, I only read those links diagonally. I think common sense it's all what's needed, after all.

Comment: I was walking from Los Arcos to Arróniz in Navarra in 2015.  A policeman came zooming out of Arróniz on a motorcycle and gave me an angry lecture (but no ticket) about walking on the wrong side of the road.  Then zoomed back to town.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are always hiking routes between cities. Specially in the Pyrenees. Ask in the tourist information point or ask the locals.

You can also look for military maps where hiking routes and walking paths are shown. Here you can see the official maps provided by the government of Spain: http://signa.ign.es/signa/

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question but I think we should leave it here because it is such important information. (And I guess it's on a par with answering "What's the best way to do X?" with "X is bad; do Y instead", which is usually accepted.) Welcome to the site!

Comment: You are right. I was not answering the specific question. I will keep to the question next time!